# Trying to filter an main array with filter array and get the result

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to filter the result based on filter value array.
Below is the main array

```
var mainArray = [
    { id: 1, Country: ["India"], Version: "v1" },
    { id: 2, Country: ["US", "UK"], Version: "v2" },
    { id: 3, Country: ["Australia"], Version: "v3" },
    { id: 4, Country: ["UK"], Version: "v4" },
    { id: 5, Country: ["UK"], Version: "v3" },
    { id: 6, Country: ["US"], Version: "v2" },
    { id: 7, Country: ["Australia"], Version: "v4" },
    { id: 8, Country: ["India"], Version: "v2" }
];
```

This is the filter condition:

```
var filterValue = [
    {
        name: "Country",
        value: [
            { text: "India", checked: true },
            { text: "US", checked: true },
            { text: "UK", checked: false },
            { text: "Australia", checked: false }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Version",
        value: [
            { text: "v1", checked: true },
            { text: "v2", checked: true },
            { text: "v3", checked: false },
            { text: "v4", checked: false }
        ]

    }
]
```

Below is the resultArray based on the filterValue i am trying to get:

```
var resultArray = [
    { id: 1, Country: ["India"], Version: "v1" },
    { id: 2, Country: ["US", "UK"], Version: "v2" },
    { id: 6, Country: ["US"], Version: "v2" },
    { id: 8, Country: ["India"], Version: "v2" }
];
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You forgot to add the actual code you're having issues with.

Comment: Also, you cannot have two `resultArray` - What is actually the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `AND` on all your filters, use something like this:

```js
let results = mainArray.filter(main => {

  // map every filter on each main value
  let filters = filterValue.map(filter => {

    // normalize filter values
    let key = filter.name,
        val = filter.value.filter(r => r.checked).map(r => r.text);
    // console.log(key, val);
    // > "Country", [ 'India', 'US' ]
    // > "Version", [ 'v1', 'v2' ]  
    
    let prop = main[key];

    // filter out empties
    if (!prop)
      return 0;

    // single string to an array
    if (!Array.isArray(prop))
      prop = [prop];

    // intersect prop and val arrays
    return prop.filter(r => val.includes(r)).length
  });
  
  // return wether all conditions match
  return filters.every(r => !!r);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used these `JavaScript Array Methods`: **[filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)**, **[find()](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_find.asp)**, and **[includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp)**

Hope this helps:

```js
        var mainArray = [
            { id: 1, Country: ["India"], Version: "v1" },
            { id: 2, Country: ["US", "UK"], Version: "v2" },
            { id: 3, Country: ["Australia"], Version: "v3" },
            { id: 4, Country: ["UK"], Version: "v4" },
            { id: 5, Country: ["UK"], Version: "v3" },
            { id: 6, Country: ["US"], Version: "v2" },
            { id: 7, Country: ["Australia"], Version: "v4" },
            { id: 8, Country: ["India"], Version: "v2" }];

        var filterValue=[{
            name: "Country",
            value: [
                    { text: "India", checked: true },
                    { text: "US", checked: true },
                    { text: "UK", checked: false },
                    { text: "Australia", checked: false }
                ]}, {
             name: "Version",
             value: [
                    { text: "v1", checked: true },
                    { text: "v2", checked: true },
                    { text: "v3", checked: false },
                    { text: "v4", checked: false }
                ]}];
            
        var result=  mainArray.filter(function(item){
            var country= filterValue[0].value.find(x=>x.checked&&item.Country.includes(x.text));
            var version= filterValue[1].value.find(x=>x.checked&&x.text==item.Version);
            return country&&version;
        });

        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result[i]));
```